# How to test an RFC module that exists only in remote system?

Tags: abap, saprfc, function-module

I'm debugging a solution where a program in one SAP system (`A`) calls a remote-enabled function module in a different SAP system (`B`) via RFC connection.

Is there a way to 'test-run' the RFC from `A`, like we normally do with SE37 for local function modules? The remote function module does not exist in `A`, so SE37 just gives an error message that the function module does not exist.

I can run the function module in `B` using SE37, but I need to test it over an RFC connection.

Comment: Have you tried to test the RFC connections on both sys via sm59?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options in the calling system:

1. Create a shell ABAP program to call the FM, run in SE38;
2. Create a shell of the FM with just the parameters, run in SE37.

I do not believe there is a way to do this without any programming in the calling system. To generate the test environment in SE37 the transaction needs to know the interface of the FM.

Comment: Really nice explanation in that last sentence. Of course SE37 needs to know the interface.